# Kafka issues when restarting consumers often

Tags: java, multithreading, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have a pipeline that creates five threads per minute, each thread does the following:

1. Create a KafkaConsumer using ZookeeperConsumerConnector
2. Consume messages until one minute passes

Once that the minute is up, the threads are killed and the process is repeated. Note that all the threads are using the same **groupId**.

After some time, I'd say between 30min and a few hours, I start seeing this exception for each thread and they stop consuming messages:

error during sycedRebalance (kafka.consumer.ZookeeperConsumerConnector)
kafka.common.ConsumerRebalanceFailedException:can't rebalance after 4 retries at kafka.consumer.ZookeeperConsumerConnector$ZKRebalancerListener.syncedRebalance(ZookeeperConsumerConnector.scala:633)
    at kafka.consumer.ZookeeperConsumerConnector$ZKRebalancerListener$$anon$1.run(ZookeeperConsumerConnector.scala:551)

This keeps happening even after all the threads are killed, the Kafka consumers closed and new ones are created.

If I run this leaving the threads always alive it does not seem to be any issues.

Should Kafka support a case like this where the consumers for a given groupId are constantly being created and removed after a period of time?

I'm using Kafka 0.8.2.1

Thanks!

Comment: Basically it should work. But you pattern is quite odd in the first place.

Comment: could you search 'exception during rebalance' or 'Rebalancing attempt failed' in the server.log? Need to make sure what caused the failure.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the solution for this problem is to upgrade Kafka, since this is a known problem for Kafka 0.8.+. 
This should be fixed in 0.9.+, more details here: https://github.com/IBMStreams/streamsx.messaging/issues/125